# Regular Expression(pattern) Attribute Separation

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I am using the logstash filter grok and I need a pattern(regEx) for this expression:

> van=FpP2N410E%252FbhMY%252FBvfstlbL6YmtlPKiQ%253D&colour=7&hv=2701

I tried it with this solution, but the "colour" wasn't seperated from the "van".

> ((colour=%{NUMBER:Colour})|(van=%{GREEDYDATA:VAN}))&((colour=%{NUMBER:Colour})|(
>   hV=%{NUMBER:hV}))

I need the OR because of different orders of the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to define a new pattern VAN [A-Za-z0-9%]+

> ((colour=%{NUMBER:Colour})|(van=%{VAN:VAN}))&((colour=%{NUMBER:Colour})|(
>   hV=%{NUMBER:hV}))

Comment: What about just `van=(?<VAN>[^&]+)(?:&colour=%{NUMBER:Colour})?(?: hV=%{NUMBER:hV})?`? Or does the order of the variables change?

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel - the kv{} filter was designed for such things, and it would allow the parameters to be in any order.